# Is there a name for a poem with rhyme scheme ABABCB?

Tags: style, resources, poetry

I have just started writing a new poem, and I am thinking about rhyme schemes. The one that jumps out to me looking at the few lines I have already written is: ABABCB CDCDED... (in dactylic dimeter, if that matters).

I would like to know if poems with this rhyme scheme have a name. I would also appreciate links to resources where I might find answers to similar questions myself in future (i.e. a list of rhyme schemes and their names) and/or any examples of similar poems.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Terza rima

In poetry this form is known as **terza rima**, and also called "tercet form" or "three-line stanza form," which typically goes ABABCB, CDCDED, ...

You can see a very famous example of *terza rima* in Dante's *Divine Comedy*, and in fact many claim the form was invented by him.

Here's another example from "Acquainted With The Night" by Robert Frost:

> I have been one acquainted with the **night.** (A)
>
> I have walked out in rain—and back in **rain.** (B)
>
> I have outwalked the furthest city **light.** (A)
>
> I have looked down the saddest city **lane.** (B)
>
> I have passed by the watchman on his **beat** (C)
>
> And dropped my eyes, unwilling to **explain.** (B)

([Source](https://study.com/academy/lesson/terza-rima-rhyme-scheme-definition-examples-quiz.html#:%7E:text=Terza%20rima%20is%20a%20rhyme%20scheme%20that%20uses%20tercets%20and,line%20of%20the%20penultimate%20stanza.)) ([Source](https://classicalpoets.org/2017/01/05/how-to-write-a-terza-rima-with-examples/))

As an aside, in songwriting lingo, ABABCB is known as "standard form" or "verse-chorus-verse-chorus-bridge-chorus." ([Source](https://studiopros.com/songwriters-challenge-write-a-standard-form-song/))

Comment: @Rich That's fair, I could edit it to scoot that down to the bottom of the question or remove it.

Comment: @Rich Edited, thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: In a multiple-verse poem with this pattern, the more pedantic of poets will insist that the 5th line of the last stanza go back to an A rhyme, in order to make it sort of circular.  This is optional of course.

Comment: You answered my question perfectly, and I will not unaccept your answer, but i actually messed up in the post. Is it still a terza rima if it goes ABABCB DEDEFE...? I mean for the fifth line of each stanza to not necessarily rhyme with anything previously.

Comment: @MicahWindsor I'm actually not sure! But my best guess is that it would probably still count, as the main characteristic of terza rima is the X-Y-X-Y-Z-Y pattern and that would still qualify even if the fifth line didn't rhyme with any previous lines.